# ¿Cómo determinar en Java qué tipo de carácter es ingresado?

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa donde se ingrese un carácter, el mismo tiene que determinar qué tipo de carácter es; si es numérico, de texto o si no es ninguno de los dos. Si es de texto, el programa debe determinar si la primera letra es mayúscula o minúscula.

Sólo tengo declarada la variable.

```
public class caracteres{
    String carácter;

}}
```

Comment: te recomiendo que para cuando publiques dudas, tengas un avance sobre el cual apoyarte, pero que sea significativo ya que solo una clase, una propiedad de tipo cadena pero en realidad lo importante que es tu lógica de programación sobre como lo resolverías esta inexistente saludos

Comment: si amigo muchas gracias, apenas entro a prender y no tengo ni idea como es esto por eso pedia ayuda.....gracias..solo tengo idea que seria un if para comparar las cadenas pero el codigo que son para validar texto o numeros no los se

Comment: si amigo muchas gracias tomare eso muy en cuenta solo que no sabia como guardarlo en carácter numérico o texto...pero muchas gracias hermano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta depende de la configuración de lenguaje y codificación que se esté utilizando
puesto que de eso depende que cosas se consideran 'letras' o 'números'. Si quieres tener control
de esos aspectos te recomiendo ponerte a leer sobre conjuntos de caracteres (charsets),
configuración local (locale), etc...

Sin tomar en cuenta esas cosas, una forma bastante simplista sería la siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClasificarCaracter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char caracter;
        caracter = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().charAt(0);

        if (Character.isDigit(caracter)) {
            System.out.println("Es un número");
        } else if (Character.isLetter(carácter)) {
            System.out.println("Es una letra");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias hermano tomare en cuenta su consejo y estudiare mas..gracias de verdad